# Intermediate step for integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, functions, derivatives

Among the various method of Integration there is one specific method(it may vary according to the terms) where for instance if we have a function as:$$\frac{px+q}{ax^2+bx+c}$$

To integrate this we perform the following intermediate step:

Let $$px+q=A\left(\frac{d}{dx}(ax^2+bx+c)\right)+B$$

And then proceed further by obtaining the values of $A$ and $B$. During the process of deducing $A$ and $B$ we equate the coefficients of similar degrees of variables and the constants separately.
In this case:

$$p=2aA$$ and $$q=Ab+B$$

I didn't understand this part. How does the business of equating the coefficients separately, work? Normally we don't do that for instance if we have a quadratic as:$$ux^2+vx+w=ax^2+bx+c$$

We don't say that $u=a,v=b$ and $w=c$. Do we? Instead don't we re-frame into the following quadratic equation:

$$\left(u-a\right)x^2+\left(v-b\right)x+\left(w-c\right)=0$$

How does that work? Is it some intrinsic property of functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "$d.c\:of\:$"? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Probably differential coefficient (Its still used in some schools, especially here in India)

Comment: @VibhavPant : In that case it should have been typeset as $\displaystyle A\left(\text{d.c. of }\left(ax^2+bx+c\right)\right)+B$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: We want the equality to hold for any $x$, so in the case of polynomials, they must have equal coefficients.

Comment: Yeah its Differential Coefficient. Vibhav- Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we consider $x$ to be a solution of an equation, we are looking for $x$. But in this case we are not looking for $x$, we are looking for another way to write a function in $x$. Thus the two expressions must be equal for *all* $x$.

We can equate the coefficients because the powers of $x$ are linearly independent over the space of polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

You want
$$
px+q = A(2ax+b)+B = (2Aa)x + (Ab+B) \text{ for ALL values of $x$}.
$$
The only way the quantifier "for ALL values of $x$" can be true is that the coefficients of corresponding terms of the polynomial are equal.  That means $p=2Aa$ and $q=Ab+B$.  The point is to find the values of $A$ and $B$ that make that true.  Then you can write
$$
\int\frac{px+q}{ax^2+bx+c}\,dx = \int \frac{A\, du}{u} + \int\frac{B}{ax^2+bx+c}\,dx
$$

The first integral becomes $\log|u|+\text{constant}$.

The fate of the second depends on whether the discriminant $b^2-4ac$ is positive, negative, or zero, and the first step toward evaluating the integral is completing the square.